# react-native-navigation: Component mounting twice on startTabBasedApp

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-navigation

Screen mentioned in the initial call of Navigation API is being called twice.

Below is my src in App - root component.

```
constructor() {
    //**mobx** reaction(() => app.currentRoot,(res) => this.startApp(res))
    this.startApp('user.login')
  }

  startApp(root){
    Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
          screen: {
            screen: root, //componentDidMount is called twice.
            navigatorStyle: {
              screenBackgroundColor: colors.BACKGROUND,
              statusBarColor: colors.BACKGROUND
            },
            navigatorButtons: {}
          }
        })
}
```

I have to load some initial data for the user which I will get through an API call to the server. The call is being made twice and data gets appended (The real problem)

Is there any workaround or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Did you find the solution?